# How do I use css selectors with React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to create a stylesheet for a react app and I can't seem to use selectors.

For example, I have a reusable `<ul>` that goes in multiple places. I want to have the `<li>`'s look a certain way when they are in the `<ul className="abc">`, and a different way in `<ul className="xyz">`.

Normally I would make a style like this...

`.abc > li { styles... } .xyz > li { styles... }`

But it doesn't work. What is going on and what's the simplest way around it?

Comment: this would work, there is likely something wrong with your implementation detail

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve], maybe using a React codesandbox

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.